# Refrescar datatable después de POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, datatables

Tengo una tabla datatable que en cada fila tiene un boton para cambiar el estado del profesor activo/inactivo. El JS que llamo me lo cambia pero no me cambia el formato del botón (de btn-success --> Activo a btn-warning --> Inactivo)

Mi tabla HTML

```
<?php if ($teacher_stat == 'Activated' ){ ?>
<td data-order="<?php echo $teacher_stat    ; ?>"><button id="btnSi" value="teacher_stat-<?php echo $id;?>-Deactivated" class="btn btn-success">Active</button></td>
<?php }else{ ?>
<td data-order="<?php echo $teacher_stat; ?>"><button id="btnNo" value="teacher_stat-<?php echo $id;?>-Activated" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button></td>
<?php } ?>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', '#btnSi, #btnNo', function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    var activo = elem.text();
    var id = elem.val();
    var url = 'teachers_save2.php';
    /*e.preventDefault();*/
alert(id);
    var request = $.ajax({
      data: {id: id},
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: url,
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
                    if (activo == 'Active') {
          elem.removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-success');
          elem.text('Active');
          alert('activo');
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-danger');
          elem.text('Inactive');
          alert('deactivo');
        }

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error de petición: " + textStatus);
    });

  });


</script>
```

y el PHP

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php');  
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo $id;

        $data = explode("-",$_POST['id']); 
        $campo = $data[0]; // nombre del campo
        $id = $data[1]; // id del registro 
        $value = $data[2]; // valor por el cual reemplazar 


        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacher_stat = '".$value."' 
WHERE teacher_id = '".$id."'" ); 

        if ($value == "Activated" ) { echo ("exitoso"); } else { echo ("noexitoso"); }

?>
```

Comment: Por favor, especifica la duda y pon un ejemplo del HTML para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Gracias :)

Comment: He añadido el código HTML que tengo (parte de la tabla). La duda es cómo refrescar los datos de la tabla datatable porque para que me aparezca el boton cambiado de color necesito refrescar con F5 manualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según he podido analizar el problema se encuentra que dentro del if estas cambiando cuando esta activo a activo en vez de a inactivo. Te dejo el ejemplo sin la request.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnSi, #btnNo', function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    var activo = elem.text();
    var id = elem.val();
    var url = 'teachers_save2.php';
    /*e.preventDefault();*/
alert(id);
                    if (activo == 'Active') {
          elem.removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-success');
          elem.text('Inactive');
          alert('activo');
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-danger');
          elem.text('Active');
          alert('deactivo');
        }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnSi" value="1">Active</button>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección... muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo @osiris85